# Show Isomorphism Involving Dual Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, functional-equations, dual-spaces

Given finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over af field $F$, show that there is an isomorphism $\phi: L(V,W) \rightarrow W \otimes_F V^*$ such that $\phi(STR)=(S \otimes R^*) \phi (T)$.

Here $L(V,W)$ denotes the space of linear maps from $V$ to $W$, $V^*$ denotes the dual space $L(V,F)$, and $R^*\in L(V^*,V^*)$ denotes the dual operator to R.

In order to show isomorphism, we have to show that $\phi$ is injective, surjective, and linear.

This is what I have so far:

Injectivity:

Let $v\in V$. And suppose $\phi(STR)(v)=0$.

Then $(S \otimes R^*) \phi (T)(v)=(S\phi (T)(v),R^*\phi (T)(v))=0$

I think my problem is that I'm not sure what to do with all the notations. Like from here, I'm already confused. And I'm not sure whether the above even makes since.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn’t makes sense to me. Where is this problem come from? What is $W \otimes_F V^*$ for you?

Comment: I'm studying for an upcoming linear algebra test. This problem is from some past exam. $W \otimes_F V^*$ for me, is the direct product of $W $ and $ V^*$.

Comment: Direct product? Or tensor product? What is $STR$? $S \otimes R^*$? And $(S \otimes R^*)\phi(T)$ suggests that there is a product in $W \otimes_F V^*$, how is it?

Comment: @Korn Under the usual definition of the **tensor product** (which is what your $\otimes$ seems to refer to), there is no standard interpretation of the expression $\alpha(v)$ for $\alpha \in W \otimes_F V^*$. So, what exactly do you mean by $\phi(STR)(v)$?

Comment: @Korn Also, your approach is fundamentally flawed. In order to show that $\phi$ is injective/surjective, you need to state what the linear map $\phi$ does. $\phi(STR) = (S \otimes R^*)\phi(T)$ is a property of the map, not a definition.

Comment: @Korn One map with this property (and I suspect the only such map) is the (unique) linear map satisfying $\phi(w\alpha) = w \otimes \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in V^*$, $w \in W$ (where $(w\alpha)(v) = \alpha(v)\cdot w$). When $V,W$ are $F^m,F^n$, this map becomes row-major vectorization.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, a better way to phrase the statement of the exercise could be:

*Given finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $F$, show that there exists an isomorphism $\phi \colon L(V,W) \to W \otimes_F V^*$ with the property that for every$R \in L(V,V)$ and $S \in L(W,W)$,
$$
\forall T \in L(V,W), \quad \phi(S \circ T \circ R) = (S \otimes R^*)(\phi(T)).
$$
In other words, for every $R \in L(V,V)$ and $S \in L(W,W)$ the following diagram commutes.
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
L(V,W) @>{\phi}>> W \otimes_F V^* \\
@V{S \,\circ\, (\_) \,\circ\, R}VV @VV{S \,\otimes\, R^*}V \\
L(V,W) @>>{\phi}> W \otimes_F V^*
\end{CD}
$$*

Observe that the goal of the problem is to show the existence of an isomorphism.
First, let $n=\dim_F V$, and consider a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ for $V$.
Denote by $v_1^*,\dots,v_n^*$ to its dual basis.
Now, define a map $\phi \colon L(V,W) \to W \otimes_F V^*$ by the following rule:
$$
\forall T \in L(V,W), \quad \phi(T) = \sum_{i=1}^n T(v_i) \otimes v_i^*.
$$
I will leave to the reader to check that $\phi$ is an isomorphism (hint: define an inverse map using the universal property of the tensor product) and that the desired property is fullfilled.

If something about the notation or the exercise is still not clear, tell me. I hope this helps.

P.S. The assumption that $W$ is finite-dimensional is not necessary.

Comment: Can you give some more detail on how to define the appropriate inverse map?

Comment: Actually, for that matter, can you show how it satisfies the desired property? I've been playing around with it but don't see it.

Comment: @MathFrak96 First prove that the map $W \times V^* \to L(V,W)$, $(w,f) \mapsto f(\_)w$ is bilinear. Now, by the universal property of the tensor product, we have a linear map $\psi \colon W \otimes_F V^* \to L(V,W)$ such that $\psi(w \otimes f) = f(\_)w$. Prove that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are inverses to each other. Once this is done, prove that the diagram commutes but with $\psi$ instead of $\phi$.

Comment: @MathFrak96 A direct proof of $\phi(S \circ T \circ R) = (S \otimes R^*)(\phi(T))$ is difficult, but possible, just note that $\phi(S \circ T \circ R) = \sum_{j=1}^n S(T(R(v_j))) \otimes v_j^*$ and that $(S \otimes R^*)(\phi(T)) = \sum_{i=1}^n S(T(v_i)) \otimes R^*(v_i^*)$, so the equality follows by writting $R(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}v_i$, which implies that $R^*(v_i^*) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}v_j^*$.